# Adding days to date columns using IF statements in R

Tags: r, date, if-statement

Here is my data

```
data <- data.frame (med = c("A","A","B", "B", "C"),
        startdate = c("2014-01-21","2015-04-01","2016-03-15","2013-01-13","2014-01-02"),
        enddate = c("2014-11-21","2016-04-01","2017-04-15","2013-12-13","2015-09-13"))
```

I am trying to do a if statement to add number of days to the end date.
For instance, if med = A then add 14 days to the end date. If med = B then add 21 days to the end date.

The following code I have tried

```
data$enddate[data$med=="A"] <- data$enddate + 14
```

But I keep getting the following error:Warning in NextMethod(.Generic) :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need `data$enddate[data$med == "A"] + 14` on the rhs

Answer (score 1):

Using a named `add` vector.

```
add <- c(A=14, B=21, C=0)
transform(data, enddate=enddate + add[med])
#   med  startdate    enddate
# 1   A 2014-01-21 2014-11-21
# 2   A 2015-04-01 2016-04-01
# 3   B 2016-03-15 2017-04-15
# 4   B 2013-01-13 2013-12-13
# 5   C 2014-01-02 2015-09-13
```

First however, you may want to transform your dates to `"Date"` class.

```
dt <- grep('date', names(data))
data[dt] <- lapply(data[dt], as.Date)
```

---

*Data:*

```
data <- structure(list(med = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C"), startdate = c("2014-01-21", 
"2015-04-01", "2016-03-15", "2013-01-13", "2014-01-02"), enddate = c("2014-11-21", 
"2016-04-01", "2017-04-15", "2013-12-13", "2015-09-13")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```